# How come my simple userscript doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I made a simple userscript that hides certain matchups on a video game website.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name CSGL BO1 Removal
// @description Removes all BO1s on CSGL
// @namespace SP
// @include http://www.csgolounge.com/*
// @include http://csgolounge.com/*
// @match http://www.csgolounge.com/*
// @match http://csgolounge.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @version 1.0
// ==/UserScript==

var bo1Games = $("div.match span.format:contains('BO1')");
bo1Games.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

This works perfectly fine when running from the chrome console.

Can anyone give me a clue on why it's not working when implemented?

Comment: possibly running too early - wait for the document `DOMContentLoaded` event perhaps? or if the content is dynamically generated after such event, you'll have to watch for changes to the DOM and react appropriately

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: Agreed with X, the code should be wrapped within ready block.

Comment: @MatthewLymer Here's an example http://pastebin.com/fqWe5RXq

Comment: Works for me. Do you have access to  `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js`? What about deleting the `@require` line and changing `GM_addStyle` to `none`? Are you using the latest version of browser and GreaseMonkey?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the apostrophes from the contains:

```
$("div.match span.format:contains(BO1)");
```

Also the HTML example shows that the format span contains the string BO3 - I take it that's not your issue?

Comment: The HTML example was just an example of what it's filtering through. Here's an image of the error (still getting it with your fix sadly) https://i.imgur.com/HNkkG2U.png

Comment: If you click on script.js:15 it will take you to line 15 to show the exact code that is erroring.